# Qlikview Section Access: ADMIN affected by USER section access

Tags: security, qlikview

Currently, my requirement is each USER will only be able to see a PPMID that is defined to them. However, when I try to implement section access, both ADMIN and USER will be affected. For example I set that user Bob can only view PPMID 928391, and ADMIN to *, but for some reason, ADMIN can also only see PPMID 928391 and not ALL PPMID. Can someone explain why?

I've tried using inline, as well as importing a table file (xlsx), both have the same outcome.

Below is my code written in the hidden script:

```
Section Access;
LOAD * INLINE [
    ACCESS, USERID, PASSWORD,   LINK
    ADMIN,  admin,  admin,      *
    USER,   Bob,    123,        1
];

Section Application;
LOAD * INLINE [
    LINK,   PPMID
    1,      928391
];
```

ADMIN should be able to see all PPMIDs, and Bob should only be able to see 928391. But what happens is ADMIN is also affected, and can only see PPMID 928391.

I have also tried doing PPMID directly inside the Section Access part, instead of doing LINK in the Section Application, and I also get the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Instead of *, use " " (space) instead.